# How should i design my websites's homepage?

Tags: website-design

I have a website, www.xphoenix.co.in. Before, it's homepage had too much text but no pics, news feed, countdown timers, etc. Actually it's for our team participating in the F1 in Schools competition and other team members said that www.xphoenix.co.in/home.php is a bit boring. So I updated it, but still think something is missing as a homepage. Please don't tell me to put a slideshow because we don't have many good pics of our team together. Please specially comment on the small text box's design as that's why I'm asking the question


Thanks in advance,

Ishpreet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure, but I think these "Please review my website" type of questions are off topic for this forum. However I could myself be off there... =)

I can give you some of my personal pointers though.

- First of all, the background is awful I'm sorry to say. It's really
  cluttered and sharp at the same time and stresses ones eyes, you
  could say it stands in the way between the user and the content of the
  site, makes the site hard to appreciate and take in.
- The header panel is not aligned with the body, this makes the layout
  look skewed. Find an alignment that's consistent throughout the site!
- I would suggest a **brighter base to build from**, and    use your
  team brand colours to spice that light foundation up. Not    build
  the foundation on the brand colours, this makes the site look    very
  heavy in a visual sense.

And for the text box,

- firstly I assume that the underlined text that looks like links will
  be links eventually? If no then you should emphasize parts of text in
  another way than making it look like a link. This is really confusing for a user and violates usability guidelines.
- Having that unsymmetrical shape of the box may work for some, but it
  certainly doesn't for me. All corners are unsymmetrical, and making
  something unsymmetrical look good is not easy. It's not simply an
  exercise of putting something random together, it usually requires a
  lot of thinking and a lot of iterations. I don't know how you came to
  that design but it doesn't look finished to me. I would suggest that
  you go with a symmetrical box instead.
- In addition to this you need a lot more padding in it, the text
  almost touches the sides and that makes it both harder to read plus
  it looks unprofessional.
- The "See more" CTA has a broken button interaction to it, only the lower part
  of the button actually works, first it was hard for me to know whether this was just a dummy button that was added temporarily or if it was supposed to work. This is due to a    problem in your markup and
  you have to go through it and see how you    need to adjust the 
  tag.